# Simple way to count number of specific elements in 2D array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, count

I'm looking for a way to count how many instances of a specific character there are in a 2D array that I'm working with. For example, when I print the array out, it can look like this:

```
[['.', '.'], ['.', 'R']]
```

Occasionally this array will be much larger, and I'm looking for a nice way to get the number of instances of something like 'R' for example, so that I can use it in a future if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more condensed way would be:

```
def countChar(char, list):
    return sum([i.count(char) for i in list])
```

This doesn't need to be a function, you could use it like:

```
test=[['x','r','a'],['r','t','u'],['r','r','R']]
sum([i.count('r') for i in test])
```

Which returns 4.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I completely misunderstood your question, this should fit you nicely.

```
def count_chars(char, list):
    count = 0
    for element in list:
        count += element.count(char)
    return count
```

I'm sure there is a more performant way of doing this but I'll leave that for you to explore ;)